# Spring MVC + Hibernate Validator + Velocity

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc, velocity

I can't seem to get basic validation working with Spring MVC.

I have the following POJO:

```
public class Example {

    @NotNull(message="You must enter a value")
    @Size(min=2, max="2", message="You must enter 2 characters")
    private String value;

    public String getValue() { return value; }
    public void setValue(String value) { this.value = value; }

}
```

My very basic controller looks like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/value.vm")
public class ValueController {

    @Autowired
    private Validator validator;

    @RequestMapping()
    public ModelAndView display(@Valid @ModelAttribute("example") Example e, BindingResult result) {
        //Details omitted
    }
```

My velocity template is equally as simple:

```
<form target="_self" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="/value.vm" method="post">
    #springBind("example")
    #springFormInput("example.value", "")
    #springShowErrors("<br />", "")
</form>
```

My servlet.xml file includes:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

If I manually validate a blank form submission (i.e. validator.validate(e)), I see that my error messages are being generated, however they never exist on my BindingResult.

Any ideas why my binding result is not getting these errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was mistakenly using:

```
javax.validation.Validator
```

When I needed to be using

```
org.springframework.validation.Validator
```

Changing to this version, and modifying the validation code to:

```
validator.validate(e, result);
```

solved my problem.

Comment: If you want to use javax.validation.Validator, and JSR-303 validation, put an implementation on your classpath, like hibernate-validator.

Comment: @GaryF I have hibernate-validator on my classpath, and that's what I was using.  However the validation errors weren't being placed back on the BindingResult object, and the subsequent #springShowErrors was not displaying anything wrong with the blank form input.

Am I missing some other config piece?  Once I changed the Validation implementation, spring properly displays the errors in the markup.

Comment: Your config looks fine to me. I'm not familiar with how the velocity template tags work, but the Spring side looks good.

Comment: @GaryF Thanks for the confirmation.  From what I've seen (the chapter on validation is a mite thin) it was correct.  Basically that velocity tag acts like the <form:errors> tag, with the last bound item being the field on the command object the errors will correspond to.  I haven't tried this outside of velocity to know for sure if you have to use the Spring implementation of @Validator, but I'm leaning towards needing to do so.

Comment: You definitely do not need to use the Spring @Validator. I've done this many times with JSR-303 validators.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use JSR 303 @Valid annotation to automatically invoke validation using javax.validation.Validator without invoking it manually.

This is enabled by default by spring if you include `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` element to your application context or @EnableWebMvc when you are using Java config

For this to work you need to have an implementation for Bean Validation API e.g Hibernate Validator